# What is the best way to simultaneously fit multiple binomial and continuous predictors?

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, scikit-learn, continuous-data

What is the most efficient way to fit a linear model `w` so that

`Y = w . X`, where

- `X` is a matrix of `n_samples` by `n_features`
- `Y` is a matrix of `n_samples` by `m_regressors`
- `n_features >> m_regressors`

when

- some of columns of `Y` are binomial (categorical)
- some others columns of `Y` are continuous?

I have tried to use linear regressions that can simultaneously fit multiple dimensions (e.g. [ridge regression](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html)), but I think this is not optimal to predict the binomial columns of Y.

(If this helps, I would primarily focus on linear and logistic models, and assume that my multivariate distributions are log normal.)

Comment: A couple of things are needed to improve this post.  First, you need to improve your notation because it is not clear what types of models you are willing to consider (i.e. all linear models for continuous responses and multi-nominal logistic for categorical, or something more complicated).  Second, you need to define what parametric assumptions (if any) you are willing to make on the error terms. To do these things you may want to consider using the latex typesetting feature.

Comment: Also, before you say that you want to fit a bunch of non-linear models without assuming anything about the error terms, you should consider that a "best" solution is much easier to define when such assumptions are made and even if those assumptions are not exactly correct, the model would be very "efficient" so long as they where close to being true.